# Re-create related records on update

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma, prisma2

I want to re-create some related records on update, something like this:

```
db.post.update({
  where: { id: 1 },
  data: {
    title: "The first post",
    comments: {
      set: [{ content: "foo"}, { content: "bar" }],
    },
  },
})
```

This is unfortunately not possible as [`set`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#set) only allows to reference existing comments (by using the `id`). So is there another way during an update to delete all those related comments and re-create them from scratch in one transaction (and maybe on nested write)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/).

In order to  re-create related records (i.e. delete previous related records and add new ones) you will need to use [deleteMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries/#delete-all-related-records) along with [create](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries/#nested-writes), something like this:

```
db.post.update({
  where: { id: 1 },
  data: {
    title: "The first post",
    comments: {
      // delete existing relations
      'deleteMany': {},
      // create new relations
      'create': [
         ......your new data here....
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

See [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5456#issuecomment-772994699) comment on github for an `update` example.

Comment: Cool, I thought about this, but it isn't documented anywhere in the docs. I'll open a issue to add this to the docs or to introduce a replace keyword like mentioned in your linked issue. Thanks for the help!